# Registering a new DelegatingHandler in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to create a new Handler that extends DelegatingHandler to enable me to do stuff before getting as far as the controller. I have read in various places that I need need to inherit from DelegatingHandler then overrride SendAsync() like this:

```
public class ApiKeyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{        
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {          
        // do custom stuff here

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

This is all fine and dandy except it doesn't do anything because I haven't registered it anywhere! Again, I have seen in numerous places that I should do so in WebApiConfig.cs but that is not a part of the ASP.NET **Core** version of Web API. I have tried to find analogues amoungst the various things in the Startup.cs file (Configure(), ConfigureServices() etc) but no luck.

Can anyone please tell me how I should go about registering my new handler?

Comment: They are gone now, see [this article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1149/convert-aspnet-webapi2-aspnet5-mvc6) for example. Suggestion is to write OWIN middleware instead

Comment: As already mentioned in previous comment, look into [Writing middleware](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html#writing-middleware)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As already mentioned in previous comment, look into [Writing your own middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Your `ApiKeyHandler` can be converted into a middleware class that takes in the next `RequestDelegate` in its constructor and supports an `Invoke` method as shown:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MyMiddlewareNamespace {

    public class ApiKeyMiddleware {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private IApiKeyService _service;

        public ApiKeyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApiKeyService service) {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
            _service = service
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
            _logger.LogInformation("Handling API key for: " + context.Request.Path);

            // do custom stuff here with service      

            await _next.Invoke(context);

            _logger.LogInformation("Finished handling api key.");
        }
    }
}
```

> Middleware can take advantage of the `UseMiddleware<T>` extension to
> inject services directly into their constructors, as shown in the
> example below. Dependency injected services are automatically filled,
> and the extension takes a `params` array of arguments to be used for
> non-injected parameters.

**ApiKeyExtensions.cs**

```
public static class ApiKeyExtensions {
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseApiKey(this IApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

> Using the extension method and associated middleware class, the
> Configure method becomes very simple and readable.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
    //...other configuration

    app.UseApiKey();

    //...other configuration
}
```

Comment: Is it fair to say that we need to use middleware instead of Message Handlers with DotnetCore?

Comment: @shaikhspear yes that is a fair statement.